# cmake: pass globbing pattern to set_directory_properties ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES?

Tags: cmake

As part of our build process we tag certain binary files with version information such as git branch, number of commits, build variant etc, and install them into the local source folder.

Eg, for a binary called `"app"` we could install a file in the local source directory with the name `"app.branch_foo.91.debug"`

These tags change without the makefiles changing, so to match we have to use a globbing pattern (ie: we can't generate the matching tag during the cmake makefile-generation process).

The globbing pattern that matches is `"app.*[0-9]*"`

If I specify a globbing pattern for `ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES` it specifies this as an actual file

```
set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES app.*[0-9]*)
```

This results in

```
file(REMOVE_RECURSE
    "../../../app/app.*[0-9]*"
    ...
)
```

I've tried adding a nested `file(GLOB ...)` into the `set_directory_properties` but that doesn't work either.

- Is it possible to specify a globbing pattern in `set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES ...)`?
- Is it possible to specify a globbing pattern in `file(REMOVE_RECURSE ...)`?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by installing into source directory? I hope you are using out-of-source builds, then modifying the source directory is discouraged.

Comment: @usr1234567 Yes I am using an out-of-source build. However, as part of the internal build procedures used by our company, the built binary is then copied into the application's source directory with a particular filename, as described above. It is part of our development process, and it works for us. The question of whether it's encouraged or not is a different matter. It is the status quo and so I'm trying to find a solution to my particular problem